# Trouble Displaying Data for two SELECT queries with Nodejs Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, node.js, express

I am trying to create a small database project for class. I have set up a nodejs app using express.js for a server. I am trying to display data form the database as text in a list element and so far it will work for one SELECT statement at a time, but a second one and I am not sure why.

I get this error: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

and this is the image: notice only data from the library.books table shows, and if I comment that query then it will only show data from the library.audiobook table.

[Web app image that results from code below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRTta.png)

Here is the code I am trying to use to display the data from two tables with two SELECT queries

```
app.get('/index.hbs', (req, res) => {
    let query = "SELECT * FROM library.book";
    let query_audiobook = "SELECT * FROM library.audiobook";
    let items = []
    let auds = []
    con.query(query, (err, result) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        items = result
        console.log(items)
        res.render('index', {
            items: items
        })
    })
    con.query(query_audiobook, (err, result) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        auds = result
        console.log(auds)
        res.render('index', {
            auds: auds
        })
    })
});
```

IF I separate this into two app.get() and comment one out, then the data will populate into its correct section, but I want to have the data from both tables displayed.

If needed here is the index.hbs html that I am using to display the data, but I am assuming the issue is coming from the way im trying to call the queries above.

```
<div class="container">
   <h1>Online Library</h1>
   <h2>Librarian Portal</h2>

   <a href="customer.hbs">
      <button type="button" id="submit">Switch to Customer View</button>
   </a>
   <br>
   <br>
   <h3>Add a Book to the Library:</h3>
   <form method="POST" action="/" >
      <label for="ibsn">IBSN:</label>
      <input type="text" name="ibsn" id="task" required>
      <label for="title">Title:</label>
      <input type="text" name="name" id="task" required>
      <label for="status">Status:</label>
      <input type="text" name="status" id="task" required>
      <label for="author">Author:</label>
      <input type="text" name="author" id="task" required>
      <label for="genre">Genre:</label>
      <input type="text" name="genre" id="task" required>
      <button type="submit" id="submit">Add Book</button>
   </form>
   <br>
   <h3>Books in the Library:</h3>
   <div id="tasks_container">
      <ul>
         {{#each items}}
         <li>IBSN: {{ibsn}} | Title: {{name}} | Status: {{status}} | Author: {{author}} | Genre: {{genre}} </li>
         {{/each}}
      </ul>
   </div>
</div>

<div class="audio_view">
   <h3>Add an AudioBook to the Library:</h3>
    {{!-- <form method="POST" action="/">
    <ul>
        {{#each items}}
    </ul>
    </form> --}}
    <form method="POST" action="/audiobook" >
      <label for="id">ID:</label>
      <input type="text" name="id" id="task" required>
      <label for="name">Title:</label>
      <input type="text" name="name" id="task" required>
      <label for="status">Status:</label>
      <input type="text" name="status" id="task" required>
      <label for="length">Length:</label>
      <input type="text" name="length" id="task" required>
      <label for="author">Author:</label>
      <input type="text" name="author" id="task" required>
      <label for="narrator">Narrator:</label>
      <input type="text" name="narrator" id="task" required>
      <label for="genre">Genre:</label>
      <input type="text" name="genre" id="task" required>
      <button type="submit" id="submit">Add Audiobook</button>
   </form>
   <h3>Audiobooks in the Library:</h3>
   <div id="tasks_container">
      <ul>
         {{#each auds}}
         <li>ID: {{id}} | Title: {{name}} | Status: {{status}} | Length: {{length}} | Author: {{author}} | Narrator: {{narrator}} | Genre: {{genre}} </li>
         {{/each}}
      </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

turns out I just needed to enable multiple queries in the `mysql.createConnection({multipleStatements:true})` and then put both queries into one get call seemed to fix it.

```
app.get('/index.hbs', (req, res) => {
    var queries = "SELECT * FROM library.book;SELECT * FROM library.audiobook";
    let items = []
    let auds = []
    con.query(queries, [2,1], function(err, result, fields){
        if (err) throw err;
        items = result[0]
        auds = result[1]
        console.log(items)
        console.log(auds)
        res.render('index', {
            items: items,
            auds:auds
        })
    })
});
```